# How to Use the New Camera APIs in Windows Phone 8 for Video Recording

Tags: windows-phone-8

Is there a good sample that I can follow regarding capturing, saving, and playing video using the new Camera API's for Windows Phone 8. I've found plenty of information regarding capturing and saving pictures, but I'd like to be able to do the same thing with Video.

I have a start but performing the recording, saving, and playback is where I am stuck

```
videoCaptureDevice = await AudioVideoCaptureDevice.OpenAsync(CameraSensorLocation.Back, AudioVideoCaptureDevice.GetAvailableCaptureResolutions(CameraSensorLocation.Back).First()); 


        // Initialize the camera if it exists on the device.
        try
        {
            if (videoCaptureDevice != null)
            {
                //// Create the VideoBrush for the viewfinder.
                videoRecorderBrush = new VideoBrush();
                videoRecorderBrush.SetSource(videoCaptureDevice);

                //// Display the viewfinder image on the rectangle.
                viewfinderRectangle.Fill = videoRecorderBrush;

                // Set the button state and the message.
                UpdateUI(ButtonState.Initialized, "Tap to start recording...");
            }
            else
            {
                // Disable buttons when the camera is not supported by the device.
                UpdateUI(ButtonState.CameraNotSupported, "A camera is not supported on this device.");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("exception "+ex);
        }
```

Comment: This? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394041(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: This is using the 7.1 API's. For 8 the API the requirement I have is using AudioVideoCaptureDevice class. I'm having a hard time finding references and some samples I can put together to create a working app.

Comment: check this link: http://www.programering.com/a/MjNwQDMwATg.html